# brute-force graph isomorphism with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, brute-force, isomorphism

I'm trying to write a brute-force approach to check if two graphs are isomorphic. I am using the class networkx but I don't want to use the built in functions for isomorphism.
I understand that I have to check all node-permutations of a graph but I don't know how to do that. So how would I permutate nodes in a networkx graph?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-in functions for doing this?

Comment: I have a few different approaches to check isomorphisms and want to see the difference in running time. Also as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives a list of all permutations of the nodes of a graph H.

```
from itertools import permutations

list(permutations(H.nodes(), len(H.nodes()))
```

After that, you could compare their adjacency matrices. See the following code: https://github.com/jgloves/graphTheory/blob/master/are_isomorphic.py

Comment: Your given code does not seem to work. Firstly it doesn't know the attribute `all` in line 42. And if I change it to `if np.array_equal(a_h, a_g):` it is never true which is weird because it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, that was written a couple years ago. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Try:
A = (a_g == a_h), and then
if (elt for elt in A):

Comment: If I change it to that then all but `E~F` are `True` which still isn't right.

Comment: if (a_g - a_h).nnz == 0